# What's a good JS library for making things resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'd like to make a textarea resizable. I tried out jQuery UI's "resizable" functionality, but, much as I love jQuery, the resizable thing isn't quite there yet. I want the textarea to resize heightwise only, via a handle at the bottom-center. jQuery lets you resize heightwise only, but evidently doesn't let you place a handle anywhere other than lower right corner, despite what the docs say.

Does anyone know of an alternate library for this functionality?

Comment: Well somebody here should know, seeing as stackoverflows comment box works like this

Comment: What does stackoverflow use for this?

Comment: Yeah, the way Stackoverflow's textarea works is perfect. I think they wrote their own JS to accomplish it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about this? The [handles](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-handles) option worked fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="welcome" class="ui-widget-content">Hello, world!</div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#welcome").resizable({ handles: "n, s" });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can style the ui-resizable-handle, ui-resizable-s, and ui-resizable-n classes.

Answer (score 1):

[4umi](http://4umi.com/web/javascript/textarearesize.php) does this rather well.

Answer (score 1):

[yui resize](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/resize/rte_resize.html) allows the handle to be specified anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this [a long time ago](http://code.google.com/p/phenx-web/).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the webkit renderer in Safari and Chrome make all textareas resizable (with a handle) by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize Textarea Use **autosize**.min.js Its a Very Light weight Library (3kb Aprox). which will resize your Textarea based on typed Content.

Refer : [Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)